# how to print on both the sides of a page using libre office

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I just want to know the procedure by which one can print a documents on both the sides of a paper using Libre office.

Comment: Also provide information about printer.

Answer (score 12):

First of all you need to have a printer that supports double side printing, and have its corresponding driver properly installed.

Then using LibreOffice Writer (*I am using it as an example*), go to

`File --> Printer Settings`, select the right printer here, then go to its `Properties`

If you printer supports double side printing, you must find a `Duplex` option there. From the drop-down choose [**Long-edge** or **Short-edge**](http://www.office.xerox.com/userdoc/FAM_O2/driverhelp/db_2_sided.html) as you like. Execute print command, and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem in kUbuntu 14.04 LTS. My default settings for my printer are all correct (Double-Sided Printing = Long Edge (Standard), Installable Options: Duplexer Installed = Installed) and double sided printing only works by default on some apps. For LibreOffice 4.x I had to do the following:

### Option 1 (Current Document)

1. File > Printer Settings
2. In the pop up dialogue box click **Properties**
3. On the **Paper tab** check that "Duplex" is set to **Long Edge
   (Standard)**
4. On the **Device tab** under options in the left column, check that
   **"Duplexer Installed" = Installed**
5. On the **Device tab** check that "Printer Language Type" = **PostScript
   (Level from driver)**
6. Click "Ok" and the document you are working in should print double
   sided.

You can also change the above settings from the dialogue box that pops up when you start a print job. This will not make all LibreOffice files print double-sided by default. To do that read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15938/libre-office-change-printer-language-type-from-pdf-to-postscript) stackexchange post or see below.

### Option 2 (Global Change for LibreOffice)

For Ubuntu specifically I ran the following commands:

```
$ which soffice
/usr/bin/soffice

$ ls -l /usr/bin/soffice
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 28 18:04 soffice -> ../lib/libreoffice/program/soffice

$ cd /usr/lib/libreoffice/program && ./spadmin
```

In the pop-up dialogue

1. Choose your installed printer
2. Click properties
3. Update all the settings as outlined in **Option 1, starting with number 3** in the list.

Now all LibreOffice files should print with double-sided printing by default.

[Other reading on LibreOffice Printer settings](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Setting_up_Printer_and_Fax_Under_UNIX_Based_Platforms)

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Page Setup** and select **Long Edge (Standard)**, as shown below.

[image]